# SSRS Report Design : Present Rows of data in a column of database

Tags: design-patterns, reporting-services, report

I would need help in design of a table with rows of data from a column called txtColumn.

Adding this to my table, repeats the 1st row multiple times in my report.

It has to list different rows in order of listing.

Can you please guide how to use Visual studio to get this SSRS report fully functional please?

Added a table to the SSRS report and added txtColumn to a row.

Result on run is to find row1 repeated multiple times.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then come back and edit your question. At the moment your problem is unclear and you need to supply much more info, sample data (as text not an image), expected results etc.